# ASPX website HTML Edit

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

Good morning,

I have a website that I have to edit for a client, but the website is on a local web server that is designed in aspx. I am looking at all the files and when trying to change Form options I am unable to find the HTML code behind the runat=server

what i ultimately need to accomplish is to change the options in a dropdown menu that allows users to choose from.

I am sorry if i am unable to explain it in depth, my web programming is weak when dealing with this.

Comment: @Izzy - Yes i have looked in the C# files and I see all the pages with .aspx.cs but there is no html code pages what so ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once published, an asp.net site would compile the code behind into a dll, you cannot see the code, only the markup.

Solution is to edit your website in visual studio  and republish.

Comment: is there a way to edit that so these options can change like i stated in my question or is this something i have to take back to the drawing board and re-compile?

Comment: for codebehind `Solution is to edit your website in visual studio and republish.`